# RTC - Unable to load Source Code to my Workspace

Tags: rtc

I meet an issue when i try to load source code from my repository :

**Action :**

- Right click on selected folder
- Select Load in the menu

**Error Displayed :** 
Problems occured running initializing load wizard.

**Reason :**
Loading is only supported by workspace configurations.

Can you please explain what "supported by workspace configurations" means?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you right-click.

As illustrated by [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/170706/error-message-loading-is-only-supported-by-workspace-configuration):

> You cannot load directly from a stream ... you need to load from a workspace.
>
> So if you want to load the contents of a stream, you would create a workspace on that stream, and then load that workspace.